# Add leading zero to time

Tags: c#, text, console-application

In my console application, I'm writing to text file with the hour it executes in the following hour format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("t")
```

However, this format doesn't contain leading zero. After the text file is created I read it and then send an email with the content.

```
string x = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");
Logs.writeSummary(DateTime.Now.ToString("t"), "Succeeded",x);
```

For example, after it generates the text file this is how it will look like:

> 6:09 AM:Succeeded
>   7:09 AM:Succeeded
>   8:09 AM:Succeeded
>   9:09 AM:Succeeded
>   10:09 AM:Succeeded
>   11:09 AM:Succeeded
>   12:09 PM:Succeeded
>   1:09 PM:Succeeded
>   2:09 PM:Succeeded
>   3:18 PM:Succeeded
>   4:09 PM:Succeeded
>   5:09 PM:Succeeded
>   6:09 PM:Succeeded

What I'm trying to fix is all `Succeeded` should be aligned.

The first approach I took is to find a way to add a `leading zero` and it would fix my issue. But it wasn't successful. So I took a different approach.

I pass current hour in the format of `hh` as a parameter to the function and if the current hour is not `10, 11, 12` then I add a `space` before the hour.

```
 public static void writeSummary(string dt, string msg, string f)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Logs\summary.txt";

        string _dt = dt.ToString();
        string _msg = msg;
        string _f = f;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            if (_f == "10" || _f == "11" || _f == "12")
            {
                writer.WriteLine(_dt + ":" + _msg);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine(" "+ _dt + ":" + _msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

This fixes the issue in the text file. Everything is aligned, however, when I read it and send an email, I lose the `space` and end up with unaligned text posted above.

```
public static void readSummary()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Logs\summary.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
               //send email using line
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion on how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're voting down, please be kind enough to explain yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `DateTime.Now.ToString("t")` use a custom format like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)